# twenty 17 theme - decrease the height of the featured image on a regular page, not the home page

Tags: theme-twenty-seventeen

On each regular page there is a featured image, independent to the home page. The featured image on the regular pages is way to high and I want to make it half the height without messing up the aspect ration.  Can someone please tell me what the CSS is for that.  To be clear it is the featured image on any page except the home page.  I did this:

```
.single-featured-image-header img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
        max-height:50vh;
}
```

It squishes it up but doesn't maintain the aspect ratio.

Comment: Try adding `width: auto;` to your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **aspect-ratio** property. You can freely set the width, then the height will automatically adjust itself according to the aspect ratio you've added.

Another thing is using the **object-fit: cover;** it also keeps the right aspect ratio of the image to fit the given dimension.